# When select the options in the select error shown only in IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my `angularjs` application I am getting some strange error when i select options from drop down in `IE11`. I have used `ngOption` to create option items. The error comes only once . If i select same drop-down again error not repeated or shown in Console.The error comes only in IE 11(didn't test in IE 9 and 10). In IE8 it works without any error.

The error message is as shown below.

```
  Error: Invalid argument.
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:56:414)
   at h.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:100:297)
   at h.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:103:98)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:195:223)
   at n.event.dispatch (http://localhost:57084/Form/js/jquery.min.js:3:8010)
   at r.handle (http://localhost:57084/Form/js/jquery.min.js:3:4692)
Error: Invalid argument.
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:56:414)
   at h.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:100:297)
   at h.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:103:98)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:57084/Form/dist/angular/angular.min.js:195:223)
   at n.event.dispatch (http://localhost:57084/Form/js/jquery.min.js:3:8010)
   at r.handle (http://localhost:57084/Form/js/jquery.min.js:3:4692)
```

By looking at error message i don't get any details about error in my controller and not able to trace error. Please help

Comment: please post your code or fiddle.....so that we can check it out in IE11....

Comment: the ngoption is inside a ngrepeat and there are many ngoption dropdowns .on the ng-change function of ng-option there is lot of codes too. So i am not able to post it here. Or even i am not able to reproduce error in fiddle or plunker.

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara I was using ng-bind-html with $sce.trustAsHtml() . i removed all the trustAsHtml and it solved the error.But i dont know what caused that error?